# Combination of elements in circle

Tags: combinations

Imagine we have few elements and they make some kind of circle with 1 way connections such as:

1→2→3→1 circle with 3 elements

1→2→3→4→1 circle with 4 elements

We want to choose every member by choosing elements.
For example: circle with 4 elements we can choose 1 and 3(1,3) for choosing all members because 1 has connection to 2 and 3 has connection to 4.
But also we can choose every member simply by (1,2,3,4) order isn't important.
So the question is there are how many ways to choose all elements?

I figure out that for circle with n elements combination of $n$ by $n$ and $n$ by $n-1$ always ensure the situation but for other I couldn't.

Comment: Your question is unclear.  To me, choosing all elements of $1 \to 2 \to 3 \to 4 \to 1$ means selecting the elements of the set $\{1, 2, 3, 4\}$ in some order.  You claim that it suffices to choose the elements $1$ and $3$ since $1$ is connected to $2$ and $3$ is connected to $4$.  However, all the elements are connected by the cycle $1 \to 2 \to 3 \to 4 \to 1$.  Please clarify.

Comment: When you put 1 into your combination it means you put 2 also

Comment: So by choosing 1, 2 is promotion

Comment: But it is possible that you dont get promotion

Comment: So for example by choosing 1 you play 2 scenario, you choose 1 that also means you choose 2 or you choose just 1

Comment: All the nodes are connected yes but it should be consecutive in order for theme to be choosen

Comment: So by choosing 1 i cant choose 3 or 4 but just 2 because 2 comes after 1

Comment: If I understand the rules correctly, for the case $n = 4$ with the cycle $1 \to 2 \to 3 \to 4$, you have the option of choosing all four elements in $\binom{4}{4}$ ways, choosing any three of the four elements and being promoted to the fourth element in $\binom{4}{3}$ ways, or choosing two of the four elements, provided that they are nonconsecutive, and being promoted to the other two in $\binom{4}{2} - 4$ ways.  What makes generalizing this to higher values of $n$ is that you have to avoid any selection which leaves a gap of two or more consecutive elements in the cycle.

Comment: Exactly that is it

Comment: In that cast there are 7 possible ways when n = 4

Comment: for n = 4: By choosing 2 element : 2 by choosing 3 element : 4 by choosing 4 element : 1 way

Comment: All the scenarios for 4 element: (1,3),(2,4),(1,2,3),(2,3,4),(1,2,4),(1,3,4),(1,2,3,4)

Comment: Thats all the ways we can get for n = 4 but when n is higher what is the formula

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's use the following notation:  Tag a number by `1` if we just pick that number, and use tag `10` if we pick a number and its successor.

For example, in the case $n=4$ and where we pick `1`, `2` and `4`, and `3` as a successor of `2`, the tagging would be `1101` = `1`+`10`+`1`.

This means we want to compose a string of length $n$ by concatenations of the strings `1` and `10`.

Let $k$ denote the number of zeros.  Then we have $n-2k$ single ones because each `0` also brings an implicit `1`. In order to combine $k$ `10`'s and $n-2k$ `1`'s in any order, there are
$$\frac{(k+n-2k)!}{k!(n-2k)!} = \binom {n-k}k \tag 1$$
ways, and summing (1) over all possible $k$'s from $0$ to $\lfloor n/2\rfloor$, where $\lfloor \cdot\rfloor$ denotes the integral part, gives:
$$p_n=\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor} \binom {n-k}k \tag{2}$$
The integral part encodes the condition that $2k\leqslant n$.
What's missing are the cases where we pick the first element via indirection from the last element, i.e. tags of the form `0···1`, of which there are $p_{n-2}$ because the inner tags `···` must start with a `1` again.  This yields the following formula for all possibilities $a_n$ for $n$:

$$a_n = p_n + p_{n-2},\quad (a_1,a_2) = (1,3) \tag 3$$

Computing $a_n$ for the first few $n$:

$$\begin{array}{r||r|r|r|r|r|r|r}
n   & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 &  5 &  6 &  7 &  8 &  9 \\\hline
a_n & 1 & 3 & 4 & 7 & 11 & 18 & 29 & 47 & 76
\end{array}$$

For example for $n=5$, there are the 11 cases

```
11111
10111
11011
11101
11110
10101
10110
11010

01111
01011
01101
```

---

## Note

As it appears, the numbers follow the relationship

$$a_{n+1} = a_n + a_{n-1}, \qquad (a_1,a_2) = (1,3)$$

The recurrence relation is the same like for the Fibonacci numbers, but the initial values are different: It's the starting values for the [Lucas numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas_number), where the 1st element of the sequence is omitted. This also means that there is a simple, explicit representation similar to Binet's formula for the Fibonacci numbers:

$$a_n = \varphi^n + (-\varphi)^{-n}$$

where $\varphi = (1+\sqrt5)/2$ is the golden ratio.

Comment: Nicely analyzed.

Comment: That was really nice thank you so much for your effort and editing. I really understood now.

Comment: @Archimedes: Thanks. I tidied up the answer a little bit, as there is no real need to hande odd and eben $n$ separately.